# Unable to locate where deprecated RAILS_ROOT is used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When I load rails (`rails s`) the first line that shows up in the terminal is:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: RAILS_ROOT is deprecated. Please use ::Rails.root.to_s. (called from /Users/x/Sites/x/config/application.rb:7)
```

I have been unable to isolate where this is being used.

Line 7 mentioned above is:

```
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env) if defined?(Bundler)
```

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of your gems is using `RAILS_ROOT` in its initialization code.

From your app's bundle directory, try: `grep -R RAILS_ROOT .`

(If you are using RVM, the bundle directory will be in `~/.rvm/gems`; otherwise it may be `.bundle` within your app's main directory.)

Comment: How do I find what my app's app's bundle directory is ?

Comment: Try `bundle show rails`.  That will give you the path to the Rails gem.  It's inside your bundle, so just use the parent directory.

Comment: found the dir, but running the command just hangs on:  $ grep -R RAILS_ROOT
grep: warning: recursive search of stdin

Comment: Make sure you include the `.` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You could search for the root of the problem as Paul mentioned. But you could also try to bump up the versions of gems in your Gemfile.
The most recent cause of this is usually the bundler gem and this is (in rvm) usually in the global gemset.

Try to bump the version in the global gemset using the command:

```
gem update bundler
```