# Rails 3 - DEPRECATION WARNING: RAILS_ROOT is deprecated. Please use ::Rails.root.to_s

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting from today still this error message. I found this thread - [Unable to locate where deprecated RAILS_ROOT is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987123/unable-to-locate-where-deprecated-rails-root-is-used) - and I tried  to run **grep -R RAILS_ROOT .**, but nothing happend.
No error or information message after run this command.

Can anyone help me, please, where could be problem about this message? Thanks you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to locate where deprecated RAILS_ROOT is used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987123/unable-to-locate-where-deprecated-rails-root-is-used)

Comment: Yes, everything. I got this error after installing gem `paperclip` v 2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have specific reasons to use Paperclip version 2.3.0, upgrade. If you look in the gem sources for that version you will find it uses RAILS_ROOT in lib/paperclip.rb.